# Смена картинки товара при наведении мыши

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Магазин реализован на wordpress с помощю плагина wooCommerce.
Необходимо при наведении на изображение товара мышью запускать слайдинг картинок товара.
Впринципе js самого слайдинга я написал, теперь осталось интегрировать скрипт в тему. Вот тут у меня возникает много вопросов. Главный из них заключается в том, что я не знаю как привязать адреса картинок к скрипту.

Сам скрипт:

```js
//функция подмены src
//elem - елемент над которым происходят манипуляции
//way - массив с путями к картинкам
//i - счетчик 
function slider(elem, way, i) {
    elem.setAttribute('src', way[i]);
    // проверяем что - бы счетчик не был больше длинны массива, иначе сбрасываем в 0
    if (i == way.length - 1) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
    //устанавливаем таймер и рекурсивно запускаем функцию саму из себя
    var timer = setTimeout(slider, 1000, elem, way, i);
    //добавляем событие на контейнер с картинкой на уход мыши, удаляем таймер и устанавливаем src в исходное состояние.
    container.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      elem.setAttribute('src', way[0]);
    });
  }
  //собственно сам массив с путями картинок
var arr = [
  'http://www.stihi.ru/pics/2011/04/07/8199.jpg',
  'http://autowalls.ru/walls/porsche/autowalls_ru_390.jpg',
  'http://wallpaperrs.com/uploads/nature/earth-forest-mind-blowing-wallpaper-91990-142978533514.jpg',
  'http://mykartinka.ru/_ph/22/664889599.jpg',
];
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
// устанавливаем событие на наведение мыши на контейнер с картинкой
container.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  //проверяем что событие возникло на картинке, устанавливаем счетчик в 1 и запускаем функцию подмены src
  if (event.target == container.querySelector('img')) {
    var i = 1;
    slider(event.target, arr, i);
  } else return;
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img width="200" height="150" src="http://www.stihi.ru/pics/2011/04/07/8199.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Как видно пути к картинкам хранятся в массиве arr.
Так вот как запихнуть туда пути тех картинок, которые админ магазина укажет.
Я так понимаю добавляются картинки так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В php не силен и движок вордпресса знаю плоховато, подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: Это в карточке товара, или в категории где список товаров?

Comment: @Bookin  в категории где список товаров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

День добрый!

Рекомендую делать не через JS, а не через CSS.

В шаблоне страницы, где вы хотите вывести изображения товаров, размещаем код:

```
<?php
 global $product;
//Получаем список ID изображений товара
 $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
//Перебираем все изображения
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
//Выводим ссылку на изображение
  echo $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
}
?>
```

Далее, выводя изображения необходимо завернуть их в какой-либо контейнер (например в div, class="product-gallery").

В CSS:

```
.product-gallery img
{
    display:none;
}
.product-gallery img:first-child
{
    display:block;
}
.product-gallery img:last-child
{
    display:none;
}
.product-gallery:hover img:first-child
{
    display:none;
}
.product-gallery:hover img:last-child
{
    display:block;
}
```

Такая конструкция сработает при наличии двух изображений.

В целом, добавив немного JQuery можно расширить функционал. 
Основная мысль - не используйте URL-изображений в самом JS, обращайтесь к изображениям черех css-классы (либо в самом *.css, либо через функции в *.js).

Comment: Благодарю, возьму на заметку. Собственно я и искал на тот момент как получить и вывести картинки вложения. Уже не помню как сделал, но получилось не очень, так как грузиться страница стала долго из-за большого количества картинок.